# How to iterate over groovy class non-static closures and optionally replace them?

Tags: groovy

I'd like to iterate over groovy class non-static closures and optionally replace them.

I can get MetaClass with something like

```
MyClassName.metaClass
```

and from there I can get all properties like

```
metaClassObject.properties
```

which is the list of MetaProperty objects.

The problem is that I can't detect which of those properties are closures and which are simple objects. `MetaProperty` object's type property return Object in both case.

And about replacing: Let's say, I know that it is a closure A, then can I create another closure B that wraps closure A with some optional code and replace that closure A with B in the class definition? Should work like some sort of interceptor.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way I have tried out:

```
class Test {
  def name = 'tim'

  def processor = { str ->
    "Hello $name $str"
  }
}

Test t = new Test()

t.metaClass.properties.each {
  if( t[ it.name ].metaClass.respondsTo( it, 'doCall' ) ) {
    println "$it.name is a closure"
    def old = t[ it.name ]
    t.metaClass[ it.name ] = { str ->
      "WOO! ${old( str )}"
    }
  }
}

println t.processor( 'groovy!' ) // prints 'WOO! Hello tim groovy!'
```

However, it would need expanding as I rely on the fact that I know how many parameters it takes for the patching closure replacement

There may also be a simpler way to do this...